# Linux crashing my DD-WRT router

Tags: wifi, dd-wrt, crash

I'll start off that I'm new to Linux.  A couple months ago I tried installing Ubuntu 11.10 on a laptop (HP).  The install went great, however when setting up my wireless network, it caused my router (Buffalo) to crash.  I could not login to the routers http interface even on a wired PC.  I removed power from the router and shutdown the laptop.  Powered the router back up.  Everything worked on the network again.  I powered the laptop again and the router crashed again.  The router had been working fine for months and has worked great since trying.  It has the following firmware: DD-WRT v24SP2-EU-US (08/19/10) std.

I tried to install Mint 12 last night with the exact same issue.  I turned off wireless on the laptop and plugged it into the router.  I was able to update so Mint tells me I have all updates applied.

I Googled a bit and found people stating to move your wireless router to bg only.  I tried that with a little luck.  I was able to browse the internet for ~10 minutes on wireless before the router crashed.  Again replugging the router fixed the problem and without powering up the laptop the router has been solid  today.

Answer (score 3):

I did some more Googling and found found this post

http://forum.pinguyos.com/Thread-Ubuntu-Intel-Wireless-Driver-Crashes-DD-WRT

It does seem to fix my issue.

```
echo "options iwlagn 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf
sudo modprobe -rf iwlagn
sudo modprobe -v iwlagn
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I do still have my router set to BG only.  I will try allowing N, but it is working for now.